# centos opens only 505 ssh remote tunnels?

Tags: centos, ssh, ssh-tunnel

to evaluate how many ssh tunnels does centos 8 support, I write an app on windows that initiates ssh reverse tunnel to centos 8 through a loop

```
var session = ssh("centos", "user1", "password1");

for (int i = 60001; i <= 61000; i++) {
    session.start_remote_tunnel(i, "127.0.0.1", 50000);
}
```

after opening 505 tunnels the loop throws an exception (remote tunnel failed to start).

no error in the sshd log; UsePAM=yes; selinux is in permissive mode.

Comment: A well-known limit on the Windows side.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille how to overcome this limit?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille What limit is that? I've never heard of it.

Comment: That's why they are called "ephemeral", those ports.  The number of them may be quite limited, on certain Windows versions.  I don't know the function ssh.start_remote_tunnel and the meaning of the "i" parameter, but you wouldn't be trying to use a port already in use?

Comment: the code opens single tcp connection with single ssh session with multiple port forwarding channels, so that has nothing to do with the ephemeral ports limit.